# It and this difference

Tags: pronouns

Is there any difference between "it" and "this" in my sentences?

1. Is it your computer?
2. Is this your computer?
3. Is this your brother?
4. Is it your brother?

Comment: Brother is a person and you can not use "it" to speak about humans, people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`This` is a demonstrative pronoun, whereas `it` isn't. Using `this` is the verbal equivalent of pointing at something. You are referring to a specific object/person when you use `this.`